# Cannot open the react-foundation starter project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to React and Node, so I apologize ahead of time if this question shows a high level of ignorance when it comes to the subject. I'm trying to use the react-foundation library, and they provide a starter boilerplate at this link: https://github.com/nordsoftware/react-starter. 
I follow the directions to

1. Install the dependencies using "npm install"
2. Start the development server with "npm start".

I cannot figure out how to get the page to open in my browser. I tried making a server.js file, and running "node server.js," but I get a "Cannot GET /" error. I do not know how I can open this in by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

When you "npm start", it should tell you where webpack-dev-server is serving at in the console log. Otherwise, I can see this in the webpack config file, dev mode:

```
development.entry.app.push('webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080');
```

(https://github.com/nordsoftware/react-starter/blob/develop/webpack/development.js)

So try pointing your browser to `localhost:8080`. You don't need a supplementary server.js file.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely worked! However, I am experiencing another issue now. When I point my browser to 8080, I receive "Uncaught ReferenceError: IS_LOGGING is not defined." Thanks again.

Comment: @Zerubabbel This is an unrelated issue, but this is because it has to be defined as an environment variable in a file named ".env" placed at the root of the project (`/.env`), like this suggests: `require('dotenv').config(path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env'))`. Example: https://github.com/nordsoftware/react-starter/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=IS_LOGGING&type=. It is probably described somewhere in the docs of the project.